# Hide product variation if not in the store - WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, product, variant

how can I hide variants on the product page whose quantity in the store is 0. I would just like to display variants that are in stock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings > Product > Inventory and flag **Hide out of stock items from the catalog**

[image]

Note that this works if product is **Out of Stock**, not only 0 as availability